# Facebook Like - title and description not working

Tags: facebook-opengraph

I have created one test page in my  jboss-web.deployer\ROOT.war named test.html.

I have added facebook like button and OG meta tags. When i click on like, title and description is not shared on facebook. Even i am unable to see on popup, when i click on like button. Please help....

Please find below code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
      xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
  <head>
    <title>The Rock (1996)</title>
    <meta property="og:title" content="The Rock"/>
    <meta property="og:type" content="movie"/>
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/"/>
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://ia.media-imdb.com/rock.jpg"/>
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="IMDb"/>
    <meta property="fb:admins" content="USER_ID"/>
    <meta property="og:description"
          content="A group of U.S. Marines, under command of
                   a renegade general, take over Alcatraz and
                   threaten San Francisco Bay with biological
                   weapons."/>
     </head>

 <body>
    <!-- AddThis Button BEGIN --> 
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>


<fb:like href="href="http://157.241.56.242:8080/Test5.html" width="450" height="80"/>

<!-- AddThis Button END -->

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add a XML namespace, but a prefix instead. The following is token from http://ogp.me/ :

```
<html prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. Using a simple html file and exactly the code you posted, Facebook shows me an image, `The Rock (1996)` as title and the defined description.

Comment: Can you give us a test case, that's already not working, please?